# Why does Windows File Explorer fail to display one specific file (a syntax file from the EditPlus2 text editor)?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Using Windows 10 Pro 64 bit.

When I navigate to this location:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\EditPlus 2

I see the application executable and a number of other files, including "syntax" files. These are simple text files that define how the text editor should highlight keywords and comments, etc, for different kinds of text files it opens.

For example, there is a file named "css.stx" which is a plain text file. The top few lines are:

```
#TITLE=CSS
; CSS syntax file written by ES-Computing.
; This file is required for EditPlus to run correctly.

#DELIMITER=:;,.={}()
#QUOTATION1='
#QUOTATION2="
#COMMENTON=/*
#COMMENTOFF=*/
#ESCAPE=\

#KEYWORD=Properties
ascent
azimuth
background
background-attachment
```

However, I cannot see a file named "**sql.stx**". *I have a vague recollection that when I copied this file to this computer (from my last computer) I had issues copying it* but I can't remember specifics. I *think*, however, that instead of copying, I had to create a new file and copy the contents of the old file into the new one - something like that. In any case, in File Explorer, I cannot see this file.

However, if I open EditPlus2 and go to File > Open, I get the standard Windows dialogue box to select files and when I navigate to that folder, the sql.stx file is there (and can be opened). Further, there is a file sql.stx.bak - which is automatically created by the editor. I could not see this in File Explorer either.

I will paste the entire contents of the file below.

In the File Explorer ribbon, View menu, I have:

- "File name extensions" = checked
- "Hidden items" = checked

Why is this file not visible in File Explorer? (It was visible in every other PC where I've used this file).

Lastly, if I edit the file to change the syntax highlighting rules for SQL files, the editor picks up the changes.

I did note, however, if I right-click within the containing folder in File Explorer and choose "New", it only gives me an option to create a new folder, not a new file. I am going to guess this has something to do with file visibility permissions (perhaps because the file was copied from an older PC - but then, all the files were copied this way and this is the only one with issues).

```
#TITLE=SQL
; SQL syntax file written by nabeel.
; This file is required for EditPlus to run correctly for .sql files.

#DELIMITER=<>/="'%,.(){}[]+*~&|;
#SPECIAL_STX=sql
#QUOTATION1='
#QUOTATION2=`
#CONTINUE_QUOTE=n
#LINECOMMENT=--
#COMMENTON=/*
#COMMENTOFF=*/
#ESCAPE=\

#KEYWORD=SQL Elements
!DOCTYPE
; SQL Elements
ACCESSIBLE
ADD
ALTER
ANALYZE
AS
ASENSITIVE
BETWEEN
BOTH
CASCADE
CHARACTER
COLUMN
CONDITION
CONSTRAINT
CONTINUE
CREATE
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
DATABASES
DAY_MICROSECOND
DECLARE
DELETE
DIV
DROP
ELSE
ENCLOSED
FALSE
FETCH
FLOAT8
FOR
GROUP
HIGH_PRIORITY
HOUR_SECOND
IGNORE
IN
INFILE
INOUT
INT
INT3
INTEGER
IO_BEFORE_GTIDS
IS
ITERATE
KEY
KILL
LEADING
LEFT
LIKE
LINES
LOAD
LOCALTIMESTAMP
LONGBLOB
LOW_PRIORITY
MASTER_BIND
MEDIUMINT
MIDDLEINT
MINUTE_MICROSECOND
MOD
NOT
NULL
ON
OPTION
OR
OUTER
PRIMARY
READ
READ_WRITE
RESIGNAL
RIGHT
SEPARATOR
SIGNAL
SPATIAL
SQLEXCEPTION
SQL_BIG_RESULT
SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
SSL
STARTING
STRAIGHT_JOIN
TINYTEXT
TRUE
UNDO
UNIQUE
UNSIGNED
USING
UTC_TIMESTAMP
VALUES
VARCHARACTER
WHEN
WITH
XOR
ZEROFILL
AND
ASC
BEFORE
BIGINT
COLLATE
CONVERT
CROSS
CURRENT_DATE
CURRENT_USER
DAY_MINUTE
DEC
DEFAULT
DELAYED
DESC
DETERMINISTIC
DISTINCT
DUAL
ELSEIF
ESCAPED
EXISTS
FLOAT
FORCE
FULLTEXT
GENERATED
GET
GRANT
HAVING
HOUR_MICROSECOND
INDEX
INSENSITIVE
INT1
INT4
INTERVAL
JOIN
KEYS
LEAVE
LIMIT
LOCK
LONGTEXT
MASTER_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT
MATCH
MEDIUMTEXT
MINUTE_SECOND
NATURAL
OPTIMIZE
OPTIONALLY
ORDER
OUTFILE
PURGE
READS
REAL
REFERENCES
REPLACE
REQUIRE
RETURN
RLIKE
SCHEMA
SELECT
SHOW
SPECIFIC
SQLSTATE
TABLE
TINYBLOB
TO
TRIGGER
USAGE
UTC_DATE
VARBINARY
VIRTUAL
WHERE
WRITE
ALL
BINARY
BLOB
BY
CALL
CASE
CHANGE
CHAR
CHECK
CURRENT_TIME
CURSOR
DATABASE
DAY_HOUR
DAY_SECOND
DECIMAL
DESCRIBE
DISTINCTROW
DOUBLE
EACH
EXIT
EXPLAIN
FLOAT4
FOREIGN
FROM
HOUR_MINUTE
IF
INNER
INSERT
INT2
INT8
INTO
IO_AFTER_GTIDS
LINEAR
LOCALTIME
LONG
LOOP
MAXVALUE
MEDIUMBLOB
MODIFIES
NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG
NUMERIC
OPTIMIZER_COSTS
OUT
PARTITION
PRECISION
PROCEDURE
RANGE
REGEXP
RELEASE
RENAME
REPEAT
RESTRICT
REVOKE
SCHEMAS
SECOND_MICROSECOND
SENSITIVE
SET
SMALLINT
SQL
SQLWARNING
SQL_SMALL_RESULT
STORED
TERMINATED
THEN
TINYINT
TRAILING
UNION
UNLOCK
UPDATE
USE
UTC_TIME
VARCHAR
VARYING
WHILE
YEAR_MONTH
```

Comment: the items in `New` is controllable. Any apps can add or remove file types from that menu. Does the file has system property? Do you enable showing OS protected files? Run `dir /a` in cmd or `ls -Fo` in powershell to see

Comment: "Hide protected operating system files"  should also be selected in Explorer view options.

Comment: @phuclv - I don't understand what you are saying. (Eg. what does `New` have to do with anything?) - but gronostaj's comment resolves the issue.

Comment: @KeithMiller - there is no desktop.ini file. The "Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)" was checked ... but wouldn't that actually hide more files? Regardless, gronostaj's comment resolves the issue.

Comment: @gronostaj - yes, I found the files in that virtual/redirected location; thank you. There must be some history here - I copied from another PC to this PC and the problem only started here ... but I most likely copied the file *to* the prior PC from another PC in the first place ... or ultimately downloaded it from the web. Whatever weird permission setting exists against it, that has propagated right through all those file transfers between different OS systems. I should be able to resolve the issue from here using the info in that link. Ta.

Comment: @gronostaj - final solution to fix the issue was to cut the files from the virtual store and paste back into the application directory - I was then prompted to grant admin privileges for those actions (and of course, granted them).

Comment: @youcantryreachingme: You are correct; mistype on my part. Can't edit so deleted as you saw and understood intent. Thanks for the head-up.